# I can't get android jsoup to work

Tags: android, jsoup

Hi i need help with a tutorial i tried from ( http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/android-xml-adventure-parsing-html-using-jsoup/ ). It's about jsoup but i can't get it to work i only get a lott of errors and stuff. 
Here is my code:

```
package com.sigustgebran.appsl;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainAct extends Activity {

//blog url
static final String BLOG_URL = "http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/"; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //set layout view
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

    //process
    try {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay)).setText(getBlogStats());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay)).setText("Error");
    }

}

protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
    String result = "";
    //get html document structure
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
    //select path
    Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#blog-stats ul li");
    //check results
    if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
        //get value
        result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
    }

    //return
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
     />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sigustgebran.appsl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sigustgebran.appsl.MainAct"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>



</manifest>
```

I would be really glad if anyone could help me. Thanks

Comment: what is the error you're getting? including your Logcat on your post would be helpful to better understand your problem

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work now. I had added the jsoup library in "External jars" as he said in the tutorial, but when I deleted it and just copied it in the "libs" map instead it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement AsyncTask. I think this will help you